# How to get a seekbar after clicking button

Tags: android, seekbar

I made an application on paint. I want to control the size of brush being used in paint using seek-bar.

In the menu(options) ,I have an option of changing brush size. So, by clicking on it, a seek bar should appear and I should be able to control that using save button (to set) and then use that value inside paint.

How do I do that?

Comment: have you tried : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9000289/movement-of-seekbar-on-button-click

Comment: yes I have gone through this .But I want seek bar to come after i click on the menu option. And the value set by seekbar should be used in the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make seekbar visible inside xml or when you get its reference in onCreate method.

on button click make it visible.

Use latest values by registering OnSeekBarChangeListener on your Seekbar.

Comment: But my xml is covered by an imageview(completely).

Comment: Could you tell me how to add a button and seekbar to a xml which is covered completely with imnagview(android:scaleType="fitXY" )

Comment: Well you can use FrameLayout if you want childs to put in z axis .Put all your widgets in Framlayout and set their z orders as well as visibilities according to your need.Either you can use visibility Gone and Visible if you want controls to occupy some space with imageview inside a layout.

Comment: I have rarely used frame layout and i am new to it...I have tried something which is unsatisfactory.Here is the link http://justpaste.it/30z3 It will be very helpful if you could write a code for me. Please

Comment: Thanx a lot.I figured out.