# how to remove a seekbar from the view with a mouse click

Tags: android, seekbar

I've done something similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17506026/how-to-get-a-seekbar-after-clicking-button). Now I want to be able to remove the seekbar from the screen once im done with it. I want to do this simply by clicking somewhere else(anywhere but the seekbar) on the screen. Probably I need some kind of a clicklistener but have no idea how to implement something like this. Any tips, suggestions are welcome.

EDIT:

Just to clarify, by removing I mean hiding the seekbar and not neccessarily deleting it. And I already tried the `INVISIBLE` thing which isn't the answer to my question.

Comment: in your activity override onUserInteraction, and then check the seekbar visibility and then toggle it, if it's visible turn it to invisible or gone, and the other way around